# How to sort a Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to sort the list of custom objects and display in `Recyclerview`. After displaying the items in `recyclerview`. I am sorting the list in the `Activity` and calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but its not working.

Code in `MainActivity.java`:

```
Collections.sort(beerDataList, new Comparator<BeerData>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(BeerData o1, BeerData o2) {
                                return o1.getAbv().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAbv());
                            }
                        });
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter code:

```
public class BeerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BeerListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static ClickListener clickListener;

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<BeerData> beerDataList;
    private List<BeerData> copyList;

    public BeerListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        beerDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        copyList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setList(List<BeerData> beerDataList) {
        if (this.beerDataList.isEmpty()) {
            this.beerDataList.addAll(beerDataList);
            copyList.addAll(beerDataList);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void filter(String query) {
        beerDataList.clear();
        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            beerDataList.addAll(copyList);
        } else {
            for (BeerData beerData : copyList) {
                if (beerData.getName().replaceAll("[\\s]", "").toLowerCase().contains(query.replaceAll("[\\s]", "").toLowerCase())) {
                    beerDataList.add(beerData);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_beer_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.beerName.setText(beerDataList.get(position).getName());
        holder.styleName.setText(beerDataList.get(position).getStyle());
        holder.alcoholContent.setText("Alcohol Content: " + beerDataList.get(position).getAbv());
        holder.quantity.setText(beerDataList.get(position).getQuantity().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return beerDataList.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        BeerListAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView beerName, alcoholContent, styleName, quantity;
        ImageView add, minus;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            beerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.beerName);
            alcoholContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alcoholContent);
            styleName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.beerStyle);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            minus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            add.setOnClickListener(this);
            minus.setOnClickListener(this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.add:
                    clickListener.onAddClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
                    break;
                case R.id.minus:
                    clickListener.onMinusClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onAddClick(int position, View v);

        void onMinusClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, LoginResultCallBack {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Inject
    MyApplication application;

    LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    @BindView(R.id.beerListRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private BeerListAdapter adapter;

    private List<BeerData> beerDataList;

    private Menu menu;

    private String sortType = "unsorted";
    private Disposable networkDisposable;
    List<BeerData> originalList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,new LoginViewModelFactory(application,this)).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        adapter = new BeerListAdapter(this);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new BeerListAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAddClick(int position, View v) {
                addItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMinusClick(int position, View v) {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });
    }



    public void fetchData() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loginViewModel.fetchData();
        loginViewModel.result.observe(this, new Observer<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable NetworkResponse networkResponse) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                assert networkResponse != null;
                if (networkResponse.getPostData() != null) {
                    beerDataList = new ArrayList<>();
                    originalList = networkResponse.getPostData();
                    beerDataList = networkResponse.getPostData();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + networkResponse.getPostData().get(0).getAbv());
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    adapter.setList(networkResponse.getPostData());
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + networkResponse.getError().getLocalizedMessage());
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchBar);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Beer");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setIconified(false);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.cart:
                Log.e(TAG, "cart clicked");
                break;
            case R.id.sort:
                if (beerDataList != null) {
                    if (sortType.equalsIgnoreCase("unsorted")) {
                        Log.e(TAG,beerDataList.size()+" Size");
                        Collections.sort(beerDataList, new Comparator<BeerData>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(BeerData o1, BeerData o2) {
                                return o1.getAbv().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAbv());
                            }
                        });
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        sortType = "ascend";
                        menu.getItem(2).setTitle(R.string.unsorted);

                    } else if (sortType.equalsIgnoreCase("ascend")) {
                        Log.e(TAG,beerDataList.size()+" Size");
                        Collections.sort(beerDataList, new Comparator<BeerData>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(BeerData o1, BeerData o2) {
                                return o2.getAbv().compareToIgnoreCase(o1.getAbv());
                            }
                        });
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        sortType = "descend";
                        menu.getItem(2).setTitle(R.string.view_original);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG,beerDataList.size()+" Size");
                        beerDataList.clear();
                        beerDataList.addAll(originalList);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        sortType = "unsorted";
                        menu.getItem(2).setTitle(R.string.sort);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.filter(newText);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        networkDisposable = ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(application)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasState(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
                .filter(ConnectivityPredicate.hasType(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Connectivity>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(final Connectivity connectivity) {
                        // do something
                        if (connectivity.isAvailable()) {
                            fetchData();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.internet_issue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void addItem(int position) {
        int quantity = beerDataList.get(position).getQuantity();
        quantity++;
        beerDataList.get(position).setQuantity(quantity);
        menu.getItem(1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_cart_full));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void removeItem(int position) {
        if (beerDataList.get(position).getQuantity() > 0) {
            int quantity = beerDataList.get(position).getQuantity();
            quantity--;
            if (quantity == 0)
                menu.getItem(1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_cart_empty));

            beerDataList.get(position).setQuantity(quantity);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private void safelyDispose(Disposable... disposables) {
        for (Disposable subscription : disposables) {
            if (subscription != null && !subscription.isDisposed()) {
                subscription.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        safelyDispose(networkDisposable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void showProgress() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgress() {

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hi @XoXo, could you show full your `MainActivity.java`, please?

Comment: @SonhnLab updated

Comment: I think you are sorting beerDataList in `MainActivity`, not beerDataList in `BeerListAdapter` so it's not working.

Comment: But I am calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Still not working.

Comment: You can use below answer of J. Jefferson or me. That can resolve your problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: Good answer @SonhnLab. Probably a bit better than mine as it would separate responsibility of sorting from the main activity to the adapter class. +1 for good programming practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the sorted list to your adapter. You're just calling notifyDataSetChanged() which just tells the adapter that there is new data in its class and to use the baerDataList that is currently set within the class to refresh the list. Try this in your main activity.

```
Collections.sort(beerDataList, new Comparator<BeerData>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(BeerData o1, BeerData o2) {
                            return o1.getAbv().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAbv());
                        }
                    });
                    adapter.setBeerDataList(beerDataList);
```

And setBeerDataList() in your adapter class.

```
private List<BeerData> beerDataList;

public void setBeerDataList(List<BeerData> sortedBeerDataList){
    this.beerDataList = sortedBeerDataList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put sort function in `MainActivity` to `BeerListAdapter`:

```
private void sortBeer() {
    Collections.sort(beerDataList, new Comparator<BeerData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(BeerData o1, BeerData o2) {
            return o1.getAbv().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAbv());
        }
    });
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then call `adapter.sortBeer()` when do sort action